# git pull: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, authentication, git

So I am trying to get git to work with my repo server (1.2.3.4) (debian) on my new server on AWS (4.5.6.7 / 10.0.0.111).

My repo's .git/config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@1.2.3.4:/opt/git/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-111 html]$ sudo git pull
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My public key is present in /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys

I previously I was prompted for the password for the user git on my repo server (not my key file passphrase). I then disabled password auth for the git user, and received the permission denied instead. During this time and now with the error above **I was able to successfully login via ssh**:

```
ssh git@1.2.3.4
```

With no password prompt or such:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

A successful ssh login on the repo server (1.2.3.4) looks like this in the /var/log/auth.log:

```
Feb 22 15:45:44 hostname sshd[20142]: Connection from 4.5.6.7 port 50409
Feb 22 15:45:44 hostname sshd[20142]: Found matching RSA key: <fingerprint>
Feb 22 15:45:44 hostname sshd[20142]: Accepted publickey for git from 4.5.6.7 port 50409 ssh2
Feb 22 15:45:44 hostname sshd[20142]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user git by (uid=0)
```

When I try git pull this is what auth.log looks like:

```
Feb 22 15:46:41 hostname sshd[20177]: Connection from 4.5.6.7 port 50410
```

Then nothing more.

How can I debug the git ssh authentication failure for git when the normal ssh command works perfectly?

Comment: Could also be a bug if you are running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44753293/1156933

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do `git pull` under `sudo`, which is the problem. Doing only

```
git pull
```

will work for you. Also doing

```
sudo ssh git@1.2.3.4
```

will fail for you. The problem is that `sudo` changes user and it does no longer see your identity file `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa` (it searches in `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`). Do the `pull` with your normal user or copy/move your key to appropriate location for the target user (`root`).

Answer (score 1):

Your ssh key is not unvalidate.

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"` will generate ssh key for the current user. Eg:

```
$ whoami
nodejh

# It will generate the ssh key for user: nodejh
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "jianghangscu@gmail.com

# Check that you are connecting to the correct server 
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated...
```

`sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "jianghangscu@gmail.com` will generate ssh key for `root`. So that `ssh -T git@github.com`  will return `Permission Denied (publickey)`, but `sudo ssh -T git@github.com`  works fine.

If you want to generate ssh key for the user: `admin`, you can change current user to `admin` then generate ssh key.

```
# change the current user to admin
$ su admin
# generate ssh key for `admin`
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "jianghangscu@gmail.com`
```